# accounts.google.com OIDC compliancy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, openid-connect

#### Objective

Our overall objective is to support access_tokens on our resource server (1) from multiple configurable identity providers via a format like RFC 9068, in which the issuer can be retrieved and the .well-known endpoints can then be used to perform authorization.

For example, `tennant A` may register 2 identity providers `devAxxx.auth0.com`, `internal.oauth.tennantA.com` with our resource server.  In order to introspect or request user information the issuer must first be resolved, which is possible if the requests are sent to the resource server with a token in RFC9068 format.

In doing so we may provide a service similar (2) to e.g. https://auth0.com/  which acts as an intermediary with any OIDC provider, signing RFC9068 access_tokens to wrap the opaque access_token for compatibility with (1).

#### Google Identity OIDC

The OIDC spec states that the userinfo endpoint must use a bearer token supporting rfc6750 section 2 https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfoRequest

The Google OIDC documentation states that it is OIDC certified: https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect

Requests to the userinfo endpoint will only accept the form in rfc6750 2.3, not 2.1.

The OIDC spec only recommends 2.1, while 2.1 is stating that resource servers must accept this method.  I find this hard to interpret:

From the OIDC spec:

> The Client sends the UserInfo Request using either HTTP GET or HTTP POST. The Access Token obtained from an OpenID Connect Authentication Request MUST be sent as a Bearer Token, per Section 2 of OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token Usage [RFC675].
>
> It is RECOMMENDED that the request use the HTTP GET method and the Access Token be sent using the Authorization header field.

These are requirements about requests, not what the authorization server should accept?

From RFC6750:

> Clients SHOULD make authenticated requests with a bearer token using the "Authorization" request header field with the "Bearer" HTTP authorization scheme.  Resource servers MUST support this method.

While I see https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo clearly part of an authentication server, not any resource server, I read this as RECCOMEND for clients contacting userinfo, but a MUST for certified servers implementing userinfo?

Perhaps google is not **specifically** certified as a "dynamic provider" (https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#DynamicMTI)?

In the service (2), a solution would be to add configuration for the supported authentication methods for an identity provider entity; unless there is a configuration-less solution?

Comment: 1) An `access token` is a bearer token. 2) Using the `Authorization` header is a recommendation per OIDC spec section 5.3.1. RFC 6750 2.3 supports providing the bearer token as a query parameter. 3) Based on the details provided in your post, Google does not violate the OIDC spec.

Comment: I forgot to mention this item. There is a potential security risk in including sensitive data (bearer tokens) in query parameters. Therefore, it is always preferred to send bearer tokens via the HTTP Authorization header. Do not use both query and headers for bearer tokens in the same request. Since using a header is a recommendation and not a requirement, you must consult the documentation for the identity provider. I do not know all identity providers, but all that I work with support HTTP headers.

Comment: Ok, makes sense.  RFC6750 says we must not use more than 1 authentication method in the request.  It's not clear to me if this RFC requires authorization servers to accept all of the 3 methods or any subset; google identity would not respond to me with a section 2.1 authorization, and they only document section 2.3 themselves.   

I can't find reference to a declaration of which authentication method a OIDC/OAUth2.0 provider requires, maybe there is something in the .well-known somewhere.

Comment: I am not sure what your objective is. There are the specifications and then there are the real-world implementations. Consult the spec first and then write code that actually works with the implementation. There are no shortcuts to skip the second part. Vendors are not required to implement all of the specs. That level of detail is not part of `.well-known` configuration files. Tip: I have written lots of OAuth and OIDC code. My code is similar for each Identity Provider but it is not the same. If you are expecting to write code based solely on a spec, you will be disappointed.

Comment: Our objective is as stated in the OIDC spec https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#DynamicMTI `OpenID Providers supporting dynamic establishment of relationships with RPs that they do not have a pre-configured relationship`.

I assume google identity is not dynamic certified as above, which would explain why it's userinfo endpoint does not support all authentication methods as required in the above spec.

Comment: Additionally, we require the access token to be an identifiable jwt such as in RFC 9068, although it does seem we might have to be flexible on the naming of the client_id claim type; beyond this scope though, google identity `iss: https://accounts.google.com/` doesn't support jwt access tokens, this is just a question about something I've discovered along the way in writing a service that wraps such non-compliant providers.

Comment: FYI: Many Google Cloud services support `JWT assertions` which are signed JWTs. Those assertions are exchanged for access tokens, which is what the SDKs perform behind the scenes. Google access tokens are opaque and I believe are a hash value of something, but I am not sure. Some services, such as Cloud Storage, do not support JWT assertions. When working with OAuth and OIDC, you will find that most identity providers have their own value-added features. If your goal is to follow the specs only, those types of features will give you grief.

Comment: A resource server which accepts access tokens from multiple issuers can only work when those tokens have information which identifies the issuer.  RFC 9068 is a way to achieve this; the bare minimum would be the `iss` claim.  Non-compliant providers can be wrapped by another issuer, like Auth0 do for example.   For the use cases we have (identity only), I'm happy to insist compliance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a chat forum. Please post a question that can be answered without opinions and dialog.

Comment: Agreed - I've edited the question based on our comments.

Comment: 1) If your goal is to provide an intermediary for Google authorization and generated tokens, your app will probably be banned by Google. Intercepting tokens (storing them) allows a form of identity impersonation and Google implements security procedures to prevent that.